# How can I use local .eslintrc in Spacemacs?

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

I am new to spacemacs and I follow the guides in https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/%2Bframeworks/react
.

Everything works well except the eslinter do not use the local .eslintrc .

It works on Atom Editor, Sublime Text 3, VSCode. I don't know why.

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I'm running a mac setup, this is what worked for me:

assuming you've [installed eslint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint#global-installation-and-usage), you can enable [syntax checking](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/8e1af145480d53e8d32cdff2c83291889903164b/layers/+checkers/syntax-checking/README.org#install) in your `~/.spacemacs` [file](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/8e1af145480d53e8d32cdff2c83291889903164b/core/templates/.spacemacs.template#L50)

---

Begin by typing `SPC f e d` and uncommenting `syntax-checking`

```
;; spell-checking
syntax-checking
```

- resync your config by typing `SPC f e R`
- open a javascript file in your project, which should have an `.eslintrc` in its root
- type `SPC e v`

From here you can confirm that *javascript-eslint* is enabled and that an `.eslintrc` has been detected for your project.

Comment: The problem here is that this will only work if you have your dependencies installed globally. Meaning that a local `.eslintrc` will be used, but for something like `{ "extends": "some-preset" }` you will need all to install all dependencies of `some-preset` globally.

Answer (score 2):

Just use projectile(which is already included in spacemacs) to find `.eslintrc`.

```
(defun codefalling//reset-eslint-rc ()
    (let ((rc-path (if (projectile-project-p)
                       (concat (projectile-project-root) ".eslintrc"))))
      (if (file-exists-p rc-path)
          (progn
            (message rc-path)
          (setq flycheck-eslintrc rc-path)))))    

(add-hook 'flycheck-mode-hook 'codefalling//reset-eslint-rc)
```